# Spring not injecting a bean into thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, dependency-injection

1.How to inject a spring bean into thread

2.How to start a thread inside spring bean.

here is my code.

MyThread.java

```
@Component
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Inside run()");
            try {
                System.out.println("SessionFactory : " + sessionFactory);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

i am calling `run` method from below class like (Please suggest if i am following wrong appraoch for calling a thread inside spring bean )

```
@Component
public class MyServiceCreationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (event.getApplicationContext().getParent() == null) {
            System.out.println("\nThread Started");
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
            t.start();

        }
    }
}
```

spring is not performing dependency injection on `MyThread` class

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be starting threads yourself in a container. Ideally you should have a `TaskExecutor` which you pass an instance of the task (a `Runnable` or `Callable`) to execute. That way you can use a supported way of using threads an a servlet container. Next you should make your bean `@Scope("prototype")` and use the `ApplicationContext` to get an instance before starting the thread. You are now creating a new instance yourself outside the scope of Spring.

Comment: but you said in below comment that dont create new context because of memory issue and weird application bahavior

Comment: Where do I say you should create a new `ApplicationContext`... You can just `@Autowire` the context into your `MyServiceCreationListener` and use that instance to get beans from. I said nowhere you should create a new instance!

Comment: can you show in my example...please!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your setup.

1. You shouldn't be creating and managing threads yourself, Java has nice features for that use those.
2. You are creating new bean instances yourself and expect Spring to know about them and inject dependencies, that isn't going to work.

Spring provides an abstraction to execute tasks, the [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-executor). You should configure one and use that to execute your task not create a thread yourself.

Add this to your `@Configuration` class.

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}
```

Your `MyThread` should be annotated with `@Scope("prototype")`.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyThread implements Runnable { ... }
```

Now you can inject these beans and an `ApplicationContext` into your `MyServiceCreationListener`

```
@Component
public class MyServiceCreationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;        

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (event.getApplicationContext().getParent() == null) {
            System.out.println("\nThread Started");
            taskExecutor.execute(ctx.getBean(MyThread.class));
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a pre-configured, fresh instance of `MyThread` and execute it on a `Thread` selected by the `TaskExecutor` at hand.

Comment: i have not used   '@Configuration' class then should i create that 'ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' bean in  spring-config.xml file?

Comment: Whatever you use for configuration, can be xml too if you want.

Comment: will that taskExecutor call run() method of my runnable class?

Comment: Eventually something will call that.

Comment: Thank you @M. Deinumi. Its now working as i expected

Comment: @M Deinum please tell me 1) how 'private TaskExecutor taskExecutor' is getting autowired in my class/bean even if i not used '@Autowire' annotation or not in xml file and  2) if we used '@Autowire' annotation, on which basis spring inject that object into class/bean.

Comment: My mistake forgot the `@Autowired` on both fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150141/discussion-between-suhas-n-and-m-deinum).

Comment: I suppose that better to autowire:
    `ObjectFactory<MyThread> myThreadFactory` instead of `ApplicationContext cox`, it is not good to autowire full context in another bean

Answer (score 0):

Your MyThread is created manually rather than via spring context `new Thread(new MyThread());` so no chance for spring to inject a bean.

Instead you can add a trick with static access to spring context where you can get a necessary bean from the context (see [here](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/?p=154) or [here](https://objectpartners.com/2010/08/23/gaining-access-to-the-spring-context-in-non-spring-managed-classes/)).

Alternatively you can use [ThreadLocal](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html) or [InheritableThreadLocal](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_inheritablethreadlocal.htm) to store necessary objects to be used in the thread.

Comment: i just want to start MyThread in MyServiceCreationListener.... how could i do it??

Answer (score 0):

You are creating  `Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());`.Spring container will not inject the dependency and also not maintain the life cycle of bean.

Example :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PrintThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
    }

}
```

to access the thread object from spring context.

```
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {
 private static ApplicationContext ctx;

 private static final String USER_THREAD = "printThread";

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
      throws BeansException {
    ctx = appContext;

  }

  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return ctx;
  }

  public static UserService getUserService(){return ctx.getBean(USER_THREAD );}

}
```

Comment: Don't create a new context to get a single bean... You are now recreating the whole application. Unless you want a memory consuming, weird behaving application that is the ay to go.